# Inputting echo data into python code using bash script

Tags: python, bash

I am doing a project which requires that a series of echo commands be accepted as input by a python function running side by side. I am using two bash scripts and a python script:

echoex.sh:

```
#! /bin/bash

sleep 5
for i in 'seq 1 50';
    do
        echo test
    done
```

inputmain.sh:

```
#! /bin/bash

./echoex.sh &
python acceptinput.py
```

portion of acceptinput.py:

```
for i in range(50) :
    invar = raw_input()
print("DONE")
```

The "echoex.sh" script should run in the background because of the "&" operator and the python script should be started to my understanding. I even wait 5 seconds in "echoex.sh" to make sure "acceptinput.py" is already running.

What happens is "acceptinput.py" runs after "echoex.sh" has completed and nothing gets input into variable "invar". I can't run the echo commands after the python script because of limitations with what I plan on using this program for in the future-I don't this is relevant for this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just want to pipe the shell script to the Python script:

```
./echoex.sh | python acceptinput.py
```

The pipe includes a buffer for unread output. If the buffer is full, the OS suspends the writer until the reader consumes some of the buffer. Likewise, if the buffer is empty, the OS suspends the reader until the writer puts something in the buffer. The writer doesn't need to explicitly sleep until the reader is ready.